# Is there an opposite Yoneda Lemma?

Tags: category-theory, yoneda-lemma

For a functor $F: \mathcal{C^{\mathrm{op}}} \to \mathrm{Set}$ and an object $A \in \mathcal{C}$, we have $\mathrm{Nat}(\mathcal{C}(-, A), F) \cong FA$, which is the Yoneda Lemma. (There is a co-Yoneda Lemma concerning $\mathrm{Nat}(G, \mathcal{C}(A, -))$ as well, where $G: \mathcal{C} \to \mathrm{Set}$.)

What can we say about $\mathrm{Nat}(F, \mathcal{C}(-, A))$?

Comment: I am confused. $\hom(\hom(-,A),F) \cong FA$ only makes sense when $F$ is contravariant (i.e. is a functor defined on $C^{op}$), but your $F$ seems to be covariant. In the co-Yoneda Lemma (in the sense of Mac Lane's book; see the nlab article) in order to make sense of $\hom(F,\hom(A,-))$ we need that $F$ is covariant. But now you ask about $\hom(F,\hom(-,A))$, which really should be the same situation as in the co-Yoneda lemma but with $C$ replaced by $C^{op}$. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, sorry, just a typo.

Comment: I still think that your question is equivalent to the co-Yoneda Lemma. In many texts there is a distinction between covariant and contravariant functors, in particular covariant representable and contravariant representable functors. But in "reality" there is no distinction at all. These are the same concepts (not just dual to each other), since a contravariant functor on $C$ is by definition a (covariant) functor on $C^{op}$.

Comment: Actually if you view $F$ as a covariant functor then don't you get simply $\operatorname{Nat}(F, \mathcal{C}^{op}(A,-))$? It's directly the co-Yoneda lemma.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set $\mathcal{D} = \mathcal{C}^{op}$ (this is just a notational aid) then $F : \mathcal{D} \to \mathsf{Set}$ is a covariant functor, and a natural transformation $F \to \mathcal{C}(-,A)$^is the data of morphisms $F(X) \to \mathcal{C}(X,A) = \mathcal{D}(A,X)$ satisfying a naturality condition, which is exactly the same whether you consider $F$ as covariant or contravariant. In other words $\operatorname{Nat}(F, \mathcal{C}(-,A)) = \operatorname{Nat}(F, \mathcal{D}(A,-))$. Thus this is just an application of the co-Yoneda lemma that you mentioned, except you apply it to $F$ viewed as a functor $\mathcal{D} \to \mathsf{Set}$.